# Appending a div's position within an array to a hidden input type

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click a button, I want to append a `<div>` to the container `<div class='container'></div>`. Then, I want to append the value of the number of the div within its array to `<input type='hidden' value='"+number_within_array+"'>`. So, if I click the button once and create one div, its input value should be either 0 or 1, depending on the system you use. Then, if I click the button again, the value of the new div's input will be either 1 or 2. Here's an example to visualize what I'm trying to say:

https://jsfiddle.net/crduling/yzsgue0b/8/

Comment: so take an input as an array and append value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have declare a `counter` variable ,so on click everytime `counter` will be increment by `1` . Try like below :

```js
//declaring count 
var count=1;
$(".add-div").click(function() {
 //apending div wit input 
  let append = "<div>value <input type='hidden' value='"+count+"'/></div>"; //html to be appended
  console.log("<input type='hidden' value='"+count+"'/>");
  //increment count 
count++;
  $(append).appendTo(".container"); //add html to div tag on click event

  var divs = $(".container").find("div"); //find the array with the appended divs...

  $(".resulting-values").append(divs.length + "<br>"); //...and count how many divs have been appended
   

  //How do I get it so that the numeric value is put inside of the appended divs? Ex: <input type='hidden' value='" + numeric value + "'>

});
```

```css
.add-div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: 5%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.find {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  width: 10%;
  height: 5%;
  right: 0;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.resulting-values {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>

<div class='resulting-values'></div>

<button class="add-div">Add div</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a external variable and inside the function increment it:

```js
let counter = 0;

$('.add-div').click(function() {
  let append = `<div>value ${counter}</div>`; 

  $(append).appendTo('.container'); 

  let inputHidden = `<input type="hidden" value="${counter}">`;

  $('.resulting-values').append(inputHidden);
  
  counter++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>

<div class='resulting-values'></div>

<button class="add-div">Add div</button>
```